# Trying to pass URL parameter to CBV to filter & return queryset

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Your time is very much appreciated!

I've spent all day on this, got past most errors except this ValueError:

ValueError at /products/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Protein'

So somewhere along the line its trying to convert 'Protein' to an integer and obviously thats not cool. Please enlighten me! I just want to sort the products by category field to display as list.

db traceback...

```
def get_prep_value(self, value):
        from django.db.models.expressions import OuterRef
        value = super().get_prep_value(value)
        if value is None or isinstance(value, OuterRef):
            return value
        return int(value) …
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, **kwargs):
        assert not cls._meta.auto_field, "Model %s can't have more than one AutoField." % cls._meta.label
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, **kwargs)
        cls._meta.auto_field = self
```

views.py (category is ManytoMany relation with Item model)

```
class BrowseProductsView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'products.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = Item.objects.filter(category__exact='Protein')
        return queryset
```

urls.py...

```
path('products/<str:category>/', BrowseProductsView.as_view(), name='browse-products')
```

template...

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'store:products' category='Protein' %}">Protein</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
queryset=Item.objects.filter(category__name__exact=
'Protein'
```

Let's say you have 'name' field for 'Protein' in category table.